# How to write throws(in java) like code in golang

Tags: go

Is there any way in Golang for a func to "throws"(like in java) an error?
Through Which I can specify , my func may return error and caller needs to handle the error.

I am just trying to mimic "throws" like approach which we have in java. 
May be this is very basic elementary type question , sorry for that , I am new in golang.

Note : I have tried panic, defer, recover , but problem is that if both the functions/methods is in same go file it is working properly , but if suppose both(caller and func) are different go file it is starting a different go routine , "defer" at caller level is not working properly.

I guess this approach is not also equivalent like "throws" , where function provider is not handling the error but caller did that , and take the recovery action. Function body provider just specify it may return some exception and caller have to handle the exception.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: In Go you don't throw, you return error values. Take a look at the std lib and the pattern will become obvious. For example (https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open).

Comment: @mkopriva, thanks for prompt response … my question was about "throws" not "throw" , where caller bound to handle or re throw (return in case of go) error/exception if caller use my function in his/her code..

Comment: There is no "throws" nor "throw" in Go. You already seem to be aware about error `return`s in Go and that's what you should be using. Is it insufficient?

Comment: thanks a lot… got you point , yes we can return the error and/or output. just one last thing , is there any way through which I can  , forced into to handle the error to the caller , as func body provider... ?

Comment: If by "bound" you mean that the compiler should complain if the caller ignores the error then there's no such thing in Go. A caller can simply choose to discard the returned error by assigning it to the blank identifier and there's nothing you can do about that as the implementer of the called function. However ignoring errors is heavily discouraged by the community and anyone who doesn't follow the convention and ends up with a broken program can blame only themselves.

Comment: The most you can do is to provide extra documentation for your function that warns its users of the dangers of ignoring the returned error value and, if applicable, additionally provide details about how the error should be handled if it's not `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. Go does not support throwing exceptions.

As you have noticed, you can panic and recover, but it's not the same thing.